# PHP Facebook-style Date

Tags: php, facebook, date

I created a PHP script for my blog. I'm trying to convert a UNIX timestamp to display like Facebook. Example, when you see posts or comments placed on Twitter Facebook you see the date/time displayed like "**10 mins ago**" or "**20 days ago**" or "**1 week ago**".

I found a PHP script but I couldn't add in my script. Can you help me please?

```
<?php
//Function for inserting post
function insertPost()
{
    if (isset($_POST['sub'])) {
        global $con;
        global $user_id;
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $content = $_POST['content'];
        $topic = $_POST['topic'];
        $adfile = $_POST['post_file'];
        $insert = "insert into posts (user_id,topic_id,post_title,post_content,post_date,post_file) values ('$user_id','$topic','$title','$content',NOW(),'$adfile')";
        $run = mysqli_query($con, $insert);
        if ($run) {
            echo "This is a test.";
            $update = "update users set posts='yes' where user_id='$user_id'";
            $run_update = mysqli_query($con, $update);
        }
    }
}

//Function for displaying posts
function get_posts()
{
    global $con;
    $per_page = 20;// page siralama buradan basliyor
    if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
        $page = $_GET['page'];
    } else {
        $page = 1;
    }
    $start_from = ($page - 1) * $per_page; //Buradan yukarisi bu alanda dahil page siralama icin SILINECEK!!!
    $get_posts = "select * from posts ORDER by 1 DESC LIMIT $start_from,$per_page";
    $run_posts = mysqli_query($con, $get_posts);
    while ($row_posts = mysqli_fetch_array($run_posts)) {
        $post_id = $row_posts['post_id'];
        $user_id = $row_posts['user_id'];
        $post_title = $row_posts['post_title'];
        $content = $row_posts['post_content'];
        $post_date = $row_posts['post_date'];
        $adfile = $row_posts['post_file'];
        /***getting the user who has posted the thread**/
        $user = "select * from users where user_id='$user_id' AND posts='yes'";
        $run_user = mysqli_query($con, $user);
        $row_user = mysqli_fetch_array($run_user);
        $user_name = $row_user['user_name'];
        $user_image = $row_user['user_image'];
        $user = $_SESSION['user_email'];
        $get_user = "select * from users where user_email='$user'";
        $run_user = mysqli_query($con, $get_user);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_user);
        $user_country = $row['user_country'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your `get_posts()` function, you have:

```
$post_date = $row_posts['post_date'];
```

What you want to do is convert that into a raw time value and convert today into a raw time value as well. then subtract the two raw values then divide the result by 60. So under the above statement, you can add these lines:

```
$post_timestamp = strtotime($post_date);
$now_timestamp = time();
$seconds_ago = $now_timestamp - $post_timestamp;
$minutes_ago = intval($seconds_ago / 60);
```

Then you can use the `$minutes_ago` variable elsewhere in the function. For example you can add this line underneath the above lines:

```
echo "This item was added ".$minutes_ago." minute(s) ago.";
```

If you want to be precise in the timing, then remove `intval` from my code.

** Update **

In response to a comment, You'll have to apply math to determine which suffix to use.

So take `$seconds_ago` and create conditions:

```
$div_minute=60; //raw value for minute = 60 seconds
$div_hour=$div_minute*60; //raw value for hour = 60 * 60 = 3600 seconds
$div_day=$div_hour*24; //raw value for day = 60 * 60 * 24 = 86400 seconds
$div_week=$div_day*7; //raw value for week = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 seconds

if ($seconds_ago >= $div_week){
    echo "Updated about ".intval($seconds_ago/$div_week)." week(s) ago";
}else{
    if ($seconds_ago >= $div_day){
        echo "Updated about ".intval($seconds_ago/$div_day)." days(s) ago";
    }else{
        if ($seconds_ago >= $div_hour){
            echo "Updated about ".intval($seconds_ago/$div_hour)." hours(s) ago";
        }else{
            if ($seconds_ago > 10){ // Does "now" in your app mean within the last 10 seconds?
                echo "Updated ".$seconds_ago." second(s) ago.";
            }else{
                echo "Updated just now";
            }
        }
   }
}
```

In my code, I assumed "now" means within the last 10 seconds.

Comment: Hi Mike.This one is good but I mean when user send post or comment date area should see like this "1 month ago", "1 week ago", "10 hours ago" and "just now" like facebook and twitter style.

Comment: I updated my answer so that you can apply different suffixes to times besides "seconds".

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked for PHP, but the library that handles this is freely available, and is called `moment.js`. If your blog has a javascript layer, it might be easier to do this string transform client-side. See http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/from/.